# failed to send request to the http server

Tags: php, symfony, http, server

I tried recently to install symfony using the setup.exe in the official website.
Because there are 2 ways to make websites using symfony
for example to create a project instead of using this syntax :

> composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton project_name
> I will simply use :
> symfony new --full project_name
> because a lot of tutorials use the second way.
> But when I execute it and it comes to the step of downloading additional files it output"Failed to send request to the http server" and I don't know why.
> Please if anyone knows the solution I will be very grateful.
> Thank you all.

Comment: Can you run the installation again and update with a image of the error? What additional files are you try to download? You run composer install of some packages?

Comment: I used just composer to make my hole project and it worked.I think I don't need to install symfony anymore.Thank you